# Add parameters to HTTP POST request in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I've known the way to send a simple HTTP request using Node.js as the following:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'example.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/foo.html'
};

http.get(options, function(resp){
  resp.on('data', function(chunk){
    //do something with chunk
  });
}).on("error", function(e){
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

I want to know how to embed parameters in the body of `POST` request and how to capture them from the receiver module.

Comment: if you are new to this, don't even try to accomplish this with `http` code module instead more friendly frameworks like `express` or other modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would you mind using the [request library](https://github.com/mikeal/request). Sending a post request becomes as simple as

```
var options = {
url: 'https://someurl.com',
'method': 'POST',
 'body': {"key":"val"} 

};

 request(options,function(error,response,body){
   //do what you want with this callback functon
});
```

The request library also has a shortcut for post in `request.post` method in which you pass the url to make a post request to along with the data to send to that url.

**Edit based on comment**

To "capture" a post request it would be best if you used some kind of framework. Since [express](http://expressjs.com/api.html) is the most popular one I will give an example of express. In case you are not familiar with express I suggest reading a [getting started guide](http://howtonode.org/getting-started-with-express) by the author himself.

All you need to do is create a post route and the callback function will contain the data that is posted to that url

```
app.post('/name-of-route',function(req,res){
 console.log(req.body);
//req.body contains the post data that you posted to the url 
 });
```

Comment: That's is great but how to capture these body parameter in the receiver side ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the native `http` module, parameters can be included in body this way:

```
var http = require('follow-redirects').http;
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'hostname': 'example.com',
  'path': '/foo.html',
  'headers': {
  },
  'maxRedirects': 20
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function (chunk) {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });

  res.on("error", function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
});

var postData = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"examplekey\"\r\n\r\nexamplevalue\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--";
req.setHeader('content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW');
req.write(postData);
req.end();
```