# Reciving multiple parameters in post method in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters

I have a Node.js server which is handling post methods like this:

```
app.post('/app/:id:second',function(req,res){
  console.log('Post received');
  res.end();
})
```

How can I pass 2 or more parameters to my server in a URL? How should the url look like? I tried it like this but it failed: `http://localhost:8080/app/id=123&second=333`
I'm a beginner in web apps.

Comment: [Url params](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params) !== [query params](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query).

Comment: then how can I send the params to my server? I have 2 forms and I'm trying to determine which one was pressed.

Comment: Does the answer on this similar question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223868/add-parameters-to-http-post-request-in-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bodyParser` midleware, for example:

```
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.post('/app/:id',function(req,res){  //http://localhost:8080/app/123?second=333

  console.log(req.query); //{second: 333}
  console.log(req.params); // {id: 123}
  res.end();
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to form the url to that both "id" and "second" are in req.params?

Comment: If you want 'second' in params you must write somthing like that:
app.post('/app/:id/:second',function(req,res)....
http://localhost:8080/app/123/333 
But this not correct!!!

Comment: This is the situation I'm trying to figure out and please tell me what the right solution is. When a person clicks on a link like this: `localhost:8080/app/12345` two web forms should be visible. Now, when that person clicks on the web form button a POST method should be executed. I need to know which button was pressed so that I can handle it in the app.post method on my server. That is why I'm trying to send 2 parameters, the "ID"(which is 12345) and a "BUTTON PRESSED" parameter. Is your answer good for my problem?

Comment: If that was my problem, i would use my answer =)

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/app',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.query.id);
  console.log(req.query.second);
  res.end();
})
```

**Note: -**req url should be like this :- http://localhost:8080/app?id=123&second=333